# Given a matrix $T$, how can I generate a block matrix $B$ with each block containing the corresponding column of $T$ repeated $r$ times?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose to have a matrix $T$ with dimension $n \times m$. What I want to obtain is a new block matrix $B$ with dimension $(m*n) \times r$, such that $r = r_1 + r_2 + ... + r_m$ and each block $i$ of $B$ contains the column $i$ of $T$ repeated $r_i$ times.

For example, suppose $T = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 7 \\ 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 3 & 6 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$ and $r: r_1 = 2, r_2 = 3, r_3 = 2$. Then $B$ must be the block matrix: $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 7 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 8 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$

I want to know if it is possible (and in case how) to obtain $B$ with an equation using matrix operators (like products or Kronecker products), maintaining $T$ as the only variable in the equation. $T$ can eventually be reshaped in another form, but must contain only and all the original values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the $r_i$'s can also be part of the formula.

The blocks themselves can be obtained by $B_i= T \cdot \vec e_i\cdot 1_{1,~r_1}$, where $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_k$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$, and $1_{m,~n}$ is the $m\times n$ matrix, all of whose entries are $1$. Now take a direct sum of the blocks, and you're done.

$$B = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k T \cdot \vec e_i\cdot 1_{1,~r_1}.$$

Direct sum link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum

**Addendum.** The direct sum can be simulated using matrix multiplication with special matrices. (This is probably well-known.) In your case, if you define
$$E_i = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0_{n(i-1),~n}\\ I_n \\ 0_{n^2-ni,~n}
\end{array}\right], \quad
F_i = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0_{r,~r^-} & I_{r} & 0_{r,~r^+} \end{array}\right],
$$
where $r=r_i$, $r^- = \sum\limits_{k<i} r_k$, and $r^+ = \sum\limits_{k>i} r_k$, then you can write
$$B = \sum_{i=1}^m E_i \cdot T\cdot \vec e_i\cdot 1_{1,~r_1}\cdot F_i.$$